# Firebase Recycler Adapter is not showing my Recyclerview in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Basically i followed the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849?noredirect=1#comment86138702_49384849) with few changes in my Activity and it worked perfect. My problem is that I wrote the exact same codes for my Fragment. when I open my app, it doesn't show anything. Before I changed my code in my fragment from a custom Adapter to the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter, everything worked fine.

This is my Fragment class

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment {

public Button buttonsrch, openFreezer, openRef, openPantry, scrollToFreezer, scrollToRef, scrollToPantry;
public NestedScrollView scrollView;
public RelativeLayout mFreezerLayout,mRefrigeratorLayout, mPantryLayout;
public FloatingActionButton mAddItems;
public DatabaseReference mDatabaseFreezer;
public RecyclerView mFreezerRecyclerView;
public ArrayList<Event> mDataSet;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, ProductHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

@Override
public int getLayoutResId() {
    return R.layout.fragment_home;
}

@Override
public View inOnCreateView(View root, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstancesState) {

    View view = mRoot;

    buttonsrch = view.findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    openPantry = view.findViewById(R.id.ShowMorePantry);
    openRef = view.findViewById(R.id.ShowMoreRefrigerator);
    openFreezer = view.findViewById(R.id.ShowMoreFreezer);
    scrollToFreezer = view.findViewById(R.id.bringToFreezer);
    scrollToPantry = view.findViewById(R.id.bringToPantry);
    scrollToRef = view.findViewById(R.id.bringToRefrigerator);
    scrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewHomeFragment);
    mFreezerLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.FreezerLayout);
    mPantryLayout =view.findViewById(R.id.PantryRelativeLayout);
    mRefrigeratorLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.RefrigeratorRelativeLayout);
    mAddItems = view.findViewById(R.id.addItems_Inventory);

    mAddItems.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), AddInventoryActivity.class));
        }
    });

    buttonsrch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Search_Activity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    openPantry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent h = new Intent(getActivity(), PantryActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(h);
        }
    });
    openRef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent g = new Intent(getActivity(), RefActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(g);
        }
    });
    openFreezer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent s = new Intent(getActivity(), FreezerActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(s);
        }
    });

    scrollToFreezer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FocusToFreezer();
        }
    });
    scrollToRef.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FocusToRef();
        }
    });
    scrollToPantry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FocusToPantry();
        }
    });

    mDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
    mFreezerRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.FreezerRecyclerView);
    mFreezerRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mFreezerRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    mDatabaseFreezer = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FreezerItems");
    Query query = mDatabaseFreezer;

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Event> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Event>()
            .setQuery(query, Event.class).build();

    firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Event, ProductHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ProductHolder holder, int position, Event model) {
            model = mDataSet.get(position);
            holder.mItemName.setText(model.getName());
            holder.mItemDate.setText(model.getDate());
            final Event finalModel = model;
            holder.mDeleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    mDatabaseFreezer.child(finalModel.get_id()).removeValue();
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public ProductHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row_inventory,parent,false);

            return new ProductHolder(view);
        }
    };

    mDatabaseFreezer.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            HashMap<String, String> value = (HashMap<String,String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                String name = value.get("Name");
                String date = value.get("Date");
                String key = value.get("Key");
                mDataSet.add(new Event(name,date,null, key));
                Collections.sort(mDataSet, new Comparator<Event>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Event event, Event t1) {
                        if (event.getDate() == null || t1.getDate() == null)
                        return 0;
                        return event.getDate().compareTo(t1.getDate());
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    mFreezerRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    return root;
}


private class ProductHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView mItemName, mItemDate;
    private Button mDeleteBtn;

    public ProductHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ItemNameTxtView);
        mItemDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.BestBeoforeTxtView);
        mDeleteBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteItem);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter != null){
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }
}

private void FocusToFreezer(){
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mFreezerLayout.getTop());
        }
    });
}

private void FocusToRef(){
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mRefrigeratorLayout.getTop());
        }
    });
}

private void FocusToPantry(){
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mPantryLayout.getTop());
        }
    });
}

}
```

The only difference I could find is OnStart() and onStop() in activity are protected while on fragments are public

> EDIT I found another [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851451/fragment-firebaserecycler-adapter-is-not-working-on-fragment) with the same problem and apparently FirebaseRecyclerAdapter doesn't work well with Fragments

Comment: Where do you add this fragment to the Activity and why not post the full fragment code, you are missing onCreateView and onViewCreated etc. somethings you may wish to override

Comment: I've added it, my fragment extends to a base Fragment and I posted the baseFragment.

Comment: okay so, do you override your getLayoutResId() in the subclass cause I don't see that... so maybe you aren't including the right view. Also, where do you call to superclass or onCreate, you should really post full code if you want to get to the root of the problem

Comment: Yes i do override that as well. Ill update it later when i get back home. Thanks

Comment: @inner_class7 iv'e updated it check it out pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer

simply remove  `mFreezerRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`